# Find a last index of certain value

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have  this array

```
x=[0,1,3,5,6,6,6,7,8,9]
```

I know that I have 3 values of (6) how can I get the index of the last value of (6)

I'm expecting an output

```
ans= 7
```

I'm trying to use the find command but it gives me the first occurrence of the value

Any ideas?

Comment: Specify that you want the last occurrence: `find(x==6,1,'last')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max` + `find`

```
max(find(x==6))
```

or as @rinkert commented

```
find(x==6,1,'last')
```